# How to configure DJANGO with apache2

Tags: 14.04, apache2, django

I have a Django project known as "wsp" which is running just fine on a port. However, I want to move my project from a port to its own subdirectory (for example, `localhost/wsp` instead of `localhost:8080`).

I followed a WSGI configuration guide from Google, but it's still not running the project properly. Here is the `wsgi.py` script, at the root directory of my project:

```
import os
import sys
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTING_MODULE'] = "wsp.settings"
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

I've also made sure to add the following config to `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/wsp/wsgi.py
<Directory /home/grumpy/example-2/apache>
    order deny,allow
    Allow from all
<Directory>
```

I have the WSGI (`libapache2-mod-wsgi`) and the APXS (`apache2-prefork-dev`) packages installed on my system.

However, upon trying to run my project, I get the error:

```
ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES, 
but settings are not configured. You must either define the 
environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call 
settings.configure() before accessing settings
```

How do I get my Django project to work on Apache2?

Comment: May I ask, why would you use apache with Django? Genuinely interested. My knowledge is limited, but doesn't that contradict the entire point of using a framework such as Django?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the top of your `000-default` file:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess mysite python-path=/var/www/html/mysite:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site/site-packages
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/mysite/wsgi.py
WSGIProcessGroup mysite
```

Configure the file paths to where your files are stored.